# What does Book of Shadows stands for in title of movie Book of Shadows: Blair Witch 2?

Tags: title, book-of-shadows-blair-witch-2

I want to know what the significance is of "Book of Shadows" in the title of the movie [Book of Shadows: Blair Witch 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Shadows:_Blair_Witch_2), the sequel to [The Blair Witch Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blair_Witch_Project) .

I watched the full movie and did not got any hints about what the Book of Shadows is.  Maybe I missed some part or it means something else?

Comment: "Book of Shadows" was a title in the filmmaker's mind before this project. I forget where I learned that but I remember thinking "oh, he got to use that title." (No citation, therefore not an answer.) It just sounds cool, pretty much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find anything definitive, but:

1. The two main characters are researching the Blair Witch for a book they are writing.
2. The characters are a Wiccan and a Goth Psychic.
3. A "Book of Shadows" is a Wiccan text containing spells, rituals, etc.
4. The television show 'Charmed' was wildly popular at the time and the "Book of Shadows" is a critical element to the show.
5. The "Book of Shadows" is never mentioned in the movie.

Based on those items, barring anything else definitive, I think the title is tenuous and convenient and has nothing to do with the movie itself.